Why did Paul call Jesus the firstborn from among the dead in Colossians 1:18, when there was no death yet when God began creating?
Colossians 1:15-16, 18 YLT

who is the image of the invisible God, first-born of all creation,
because in him were the all things created, those in the heavens, and
those upon the earth, those visible, and those invisible, whether
thrones, whether lordships, whether principalities, whether
authorities; all things through him, and for him, have been created,
V18 And himself is the head of the body -- the assembly -- who is a
beginning, a first-born out of the dead, that he might become in all
things --


It's common to think that πρωτότοκος ("firstborn") carries the idea of chronologically first.  There's certainly association, but the concept of temporality is not a core component of the Greek word.  That's not to say temporality is not associated with the word in Jewish culture.  It was.  The first son that was born nearly always took on the attribute of πρωτότοκος. But, that's the culture infusing meaning into the word, and not the meaning the word brings to the culture.
The Venn Diagram nature of Lexical Semantics makes it difficult (ask any Lexicographer) to cleanly differentiate.  That difficulty is generated by the simple reason that words only have meaning in the context in which they are used.  So, it takes a sharp scalpel to surgically separate what the word brings to a text and what the text around the text brings to the word.  Thus the ubiquitous use of glosses in lexicons.  Glosses are how the meaning of the word was used in various contexts.
We see this close association and the distinction made by two uses of the word in Deut. 21:15-17.  The law laid down in this text wouldn't be necessary if there were no distinction between "firstborn" and "first born."  The words 'as' and 'actually is' in 21:16 point to both the association and the distinction.

then it shall be on the day that he wills what he owns as an inheritance to his sons, he is not allowed to treat the son of the loved wife as the firstborn, at the expense of the son of the unloved, who actually is the firstborn son. (NASB20)

So, there's different components to the meaning of πρωτότοκος, some more relevant than others.  The different components need to be carefully considered in their relative weight they bring to their text.
Now, the dead don't have babies.  And we know of other resurrections that took place.  See OT examples, and Lazarus is a loud example.  So, 'first-ness' isn't a strong component in this scope.  Though that meaning does hang out in the periphery.
Another expression, again from Jewish culture, helps us get our minds wrapped around how the meaning of πρωτότοκος functioned in that culture.  They used the expression "son of _____."  This expression essentially means "examplar of _____".  Take "son of perdition" referring to Judas.  He is the examplar, the primary example, of utter ruin.  You can't get any worse than that.  The point is that "υἱός τοῦ _____" (son of ____) and πρωτότοκος exist in the same semantic frame (see Frame Semantics, for an introduction, but basically, think of all the props in a play that fill out the meaning that is happening on the stage).
And so, the idea of 'examplar' and the idea of "being at the top of a class or group" are both readily available to the mind when referring to relationships within a class (ie a group).  Examples of what is meant by 'class' are 'perdition' in the one case, and 'the dead' in the OP.  This relational relativity within a defined group was part of the wiring of their thinking; some people were looked at differently than others and the class-like group-think was built into their language.  Taking a picture of the scene captures all the props in the play.  That is, this frame semantics creates a coherence in meanings.  But, the important point for proper interpretation is πρωτότοκος doesn't cohere with the English idea of first in time as strongly as it coheres with the idea of class structure within the Jewish culture.  We know that because of the usages do not fit with the English idea as well as they do the Jewish idea.
I think it's best to think of πρωτότοκος as meaning something close to "the one who holds the quintessential role".
So, why does Paul in Colossians 1:18 (and John in Revelation 1:5) say, "πρωτότοκος ἐκ τῶν νεκρῶν" (John leaves out ἐκ)?
Because Jesus, as a resurrected person, fills the quintessential role among the class of all those who were and will be resurrected.
Without meaning to sound irreverent, if we were to create a poster for a play about those who were dead and aren't any longer, we'd put Jesus as the picture.

+1 for excellent biblical support. The first born had a special status in a family. The concept of firstfruits in Torah also supplies context, and is further explained by Paul to the church at Corinth: "But in fact Christ has been raised from the dead, the firstfruits of those who have fallen asleep. For as by a man came death, by a man has come also the resurrection of the dead. For as in Adam all die, so also in Christ shall all be made alive. But each in his own order: Christ the firstfruits, then at his coming those who belong to Christ." — 1 Corinthians 15:20-23 ESV

You sorely abused Deuteronomy 21:16 and its context. The man is not forbidden from treating the son of the loved as born first when the firstborn is the son of the unloved because there is in truth a distinction between being born first and the firstborn, but precisely because there is no distinction. God is literally forbidding people from making a distinction between firstborn and being born first. Further the title firstborn is applied to the unloved son. There is no objective measure to judge the unloved son to be firstborn if he is not born first as he is literally not the most favored.

@Austin  The point is the point you yourself make in your last sentence.  You use two different terms to make your point:  "born first" and "most favored".  That's the point.  The point is not that they're two different people.  The point is that there are two different meanings.  So, if there are two different meanings, then the meanings can be applied to two different people.  Esau and Jacob are a perfect example since we know who was actually born first.  Your argument doesn't make sense if there is no distinction in the terms--exactly like Deut. 21:16.

@Austin  To state it a little differently...God is forbidding the application of the two meanings to two different people.  Stating that constraint makes no sense if there is not two different meanings to the two different terms.  One term being "born first" the other term being "first-born" (or "most favored").  So, a person can be referred to as someone who is 'born first' or as someone who is 'most favored' and by that be expressing two different meanings.  Deut. 21:16 puts in place the domestic relationship law, which makes no sense if the meanings aren't distinct.

@MikeSangrey, I think you missed my point. The term firstborn cannot mean most favored in the verses you used since the term firstborn is only used of the least favored son.

@MikeSangrey, regarding Esau and Jacob, you seem to be confusing the term firstborn with concept of the birth right or the blessings normally associated with the firstborn. The term firstborn is used exclusively for the son who was actually born first, Esau, and only Esau, and never Jacob. There are two separate words for the two separable concepts. It would be a lie to call a son who was not born first the firstborn. No individual human son is ever called firstborn in the Bible except the son who is born first. No exceptions outside prophetic discussions of Messianic descent (i.e. Ps 89:27).

@Austin  In both Greek and Hebrew, first-born and birth-right are cognates.  Basically, the one is an adjective, the other is the noun.  πρωτοτόκος and πρωτοτόκια.  בְּכוֹרָה (bekorah) and בְּכוֹר (bekor).  So, I'm not confusing the terms; they're semantically very highly related, like danger and dangerous.

@MikeSangrey, you still seem to confuse these terms as interchangeable simply because they are related. Just because words are related doesnt mean they are interchangeable. The Bible does not treat these as interchangeable but consistently distinguishes them, because they are distinct and not interchangeable in both Greek & Hebrew. One is transferable and the other is not. One relates to status and the other to chronological order. Firstborn means firstborn. It never means birthright in the Bible. It would be easy to convince me otherwise. Find firstborn used of an individual not born first.

@Austin  I guess we're just going to have to agree to disagree.  From my perspective it's you that make first-born to mean born first with no connection to birth-right.  For me, there's an undeniable connection to birth-right with a culturally and strictly enforced association to born first.  From my perspective the onus is on you to show that first-born is simply first in a sequence.

@MikeSangrey, Easy. See 1 Chron 5:1-2 (NASB & KJV are one of the more literal translations for this verse), Reaben is the firstborn even though he lost the birthright. Joseph's sons receive the birthright even though they are neither the most prominent nor were born first. Judah is the most prominent even when he neither had the birthright nor was he born first. Firstborn is normally associated with birthright & prominence and yet these are separable concepts when forfeited by the firstborn, but the firstborn is always born first. Thanks for the interchange.

@Austin  Your example argues for the exact same point I made with Deut 21.  The argument in the text only makes sense if the following is  true:  The meaning of first-born is more strongly connected with birth-right than it is connected to born first.  Otherwise, the author can't argue against their separation in practice.  In other words, first-born and born first are not synonyms.  They have separate meanings.  An example where first-born is not associated with born first is Psalm 89:28.

@MikeSangrey I previously explicitly excluded that passage from discussion (Psalms 89) because it is Messianic and thus is the whole thing we're trying to prove. If Jesus is literally God's born first firstborn than Psalms 89 is just another example of firstborn applying to him that is born first. This is true for when Israel and Ephraim are referred to as God's firstborn because they are being spiritual identified by means of the promise with God's literal firstborn, Christ, and thus even these are just references to him who was ultimately born first. Examples outside of God's son please.

@MikeSangrey, Ok. Let me really try to understand what your argument is. Is your argument that in this passage, the only reason why the strong distinction is made between who was the firstborn (Reuben), who was actually born first (also Reuben), and who was most prominent (Judah), and who had the birthright (Joseph's sons), was because there was no real distinction at all between the word firstborn and all these in the culture and mind of those reading this passage. Is that essentially your argument?

Simple answer:
Colossians 1:18 refers to Jesus's post-resurrection status.


30 But God raised him from the dead.. 32 And we bring you the good news that what God promised to the fathers, 33 this he has fulfilled to us their children by raising Jesus, as also it is written in the second Psalm,
“‘You are my Son,
today I have begotten you.’
-Acts 13:30,32-33

So Paul is teaching that God fulfilled the second Psalm such that the day Jesus was resurrected was the day he was born... again. Thus Jesus was born from the dead. The first one to do it. All other resurrections were simply a raising again. This was a rebirth.
And so those who are faithful look forward to following in Jesus footsteps:

20 But Christ has indeed been raised from the dead, the firstfruits of those who have fallen asleep.
21 For since death came through a man, the resurrection of the dead comes also through a man.
22 For as in Adam all die, so in Christ all will be made alive.
23 But each in his own turn: Christ the firstfruits; then at His coming, those who belong to Him.
-1 Cor 15:20-23

Thus, in this way, is Christ the firstborn from the dead after having been raised from the dead.

Note: Post-resurrection is also when Jesus became the head of the Church (the body -- the assembly) - and a beginning, arguably referring to the beginning of God's New Creation

I didn't know that the day he resurrected was the day that he was born. +1 upvote

@Austin - The downvote was from me. I love that you tied in Acts 13 & 1 Corinthians 15 to show the magnificence of Christ's rebirth into an immortal Son with an exulted spiritual body. But you completely disregarded how Colossians 1:15 declares that Christ was the first of God's works in Genesis and therefore the firstborn of all creatures, both physical and spiritual, mortal and immortal, in heaven and on earth. Christ is first in all things, both in life (Genesis Day 1) and in death to life (The Resurrection).

Answer
Paul called Jesus the firstborn from among the dead in Colossians 1:18 because Jesus indeed is the firstborn out of the dead!
This shows clearly that He is not the first creation of God out of nothing as some claim!!
Explanation
Nowhere in the Scripture does it say that God the Father created “anything” except through Jesus Christ.
In fact, the Scripture is very emphatic:

“All things came into being through Him, and without Him not even
one thing came into being that has come into being” (John
1:3).

(I am quite surprised how some people can twist the above plain yet very emphatic and straightforward verse! “And if they do this when the wood is green, what will happen when it is dry?” – Luke 23:31)
Yet, people misunderstand Colossians 1:15, where it says, Jesus is “the First-born of all creation”.
Then, suddenly, people jump to conclusions: that Jesus is the first ever creature by God the Father when the verse doesn’t say anything of that sort.
We can see that some versions have the same as “the firstborn of every creature”.
So, what exactly is this reference, “all creation”, “every creature” alluding to? Is it referring to the Genesis creation of the heavens and the earth?
Not at all!
The “all creation” or “every creature” in Greek is “pas ktisis”. "Pas ktisis" is always related to "human beings".
It has nothing to do with Genesis creation of everything.
So, Jesus cannot be the first ever creature when God the Father has made nothing without Jesus Christ.
All creation/every creature [pas ktisis] = human beings
In fact, Scripture refers “pas ktisis” in reference to human beings as I will prove below:
Evidence #1.

“And He said to them, Going into all the world, preach the gospel to
all the creation [pas ktisis]” (Mark 16:15).

This is Jesus’ final command to His disciples. Yet we know that the apostles never preached the Gospel to mountains, oceans, dogs or animals!
They preached the Gospel only to human beings (all creation/ every creature/ pas ktisis).
Evidence #2.

“However, you must remain firmly established and steadfast in the
faith, without being moved from the hope of the gospel that you
heard, which has been proclaimed to every creature (pas ktisis)
under heaven and of which I, Paul, have become a servant” (Col 1:23).

The Colossians heard the gospel being preached to “every creature/ all creation/ pas ktisis” of which Paul became a servant.
Yet we know that neither the Twelve apostles nor Paul ever preached the gospel to any inanimate creation or animals. It was preached only to human beings.
Jesus is the Firstborn from Human Beings

“because whom He foreknew, He also predestinated to be conformed to the image of His Son, for Him to be the First-born among many brothers” (Rom 8:29).

“And He is the Head of the body, the assembly, who is the Beginning, the First-born out of the dead, that He be preeminent in all things” (Col 1:18).

“even from Jesus Christ the Faithful Witness, the First-born out of the dead, and the Ruler of the kings of the earth” (Rev 1:5).

“And again, when He brought the First-born into the world, He said, "And let all the angels of God worship Him" (Heb 1:6).


[It is obvious that if by “firstborn” is meant the first ever creature, then there could not have been any angels to worship Him because He created them later!!]
In fact not only Jesus, but even the saints of the Church are called collectively as the firstborn:

“to the general assembly and church of the firstborn who are enrolled in heaven” (Heb 12:23).

[Obviously these saints in the church are the firstborn from the dead humans. They are not created at the Genesis creation!]
If so, Colossians 1:15 has no connection to the Genesis creation:

“Who is the image of the invisible God, the firstborn of every
creature (pas ktisis = all human beings)”

[It has no connection to Genesis creation]
Conclusion
Colossians 1:15 – Jesus Christ is the First-born from among ALL HUMAN BEINGS.
This is again qualified in:
Colossians 1:18 – Jesus Christ is the First-born from among ALL THE DEAD HUMAN BEINGS.
Both mean the same. So, no need for any unwarranted human “interpretations”!

According to your human interpretation,  why did Paul call Jesus the firstborn from among the dead, if there were no human deaths yet when God began creating?

@AlexBalilo  Because 'firstborn' doesn't mean 'chronologically first.'  It's unfortunate that the etymology of English 'firstborn' is read back into the text.  Simply put, that's the Etymological Fallacy.  See" Jewish Encyclopeida (PRIMOGENITURE) for a clear definition of 'firstborn'.

@MikeSangrey. I firstborn' doesn't mean 'chronologically first.'  does it mean then that Paul was not talking about the beginning of creation in Colossians 1:15-18?

@AlexBalilo "all creation" (πάσης κτίσεως) is 'all creation', there's no time in the phrase.  It refers to that which is created.  That is, Paul is talking about "all creation".  Think of it as "the entire space-time continuum" if you like.  Jesus therefore, has the legal right to the entire creation. "legal right" is a meaning component that πρωτότοκος ("firstborn") brings.  The focus in this text is that Jesus is the preeminent inheritor of the entire creation.

@MikeSangrey..  It seemed like you will not account for if"firstborn' doesn't mean 'chronologically first.' does it mean then that Paul was not talking about the beginning of creation in Colossians 1:15-18?

@AlexBalilo  Are you referring to verse 18?  That word 'beginning' needs to be understood in relation to 'the church', which is in the immediate context.  It probably connects Christ's resurrection to his status in the Church; that is, his resurrection leads.  It also has connotations of sovereignty.  Also, if somehow you're connecting the word 'first' in verse 18 to the creation, as if that word means chronologically first, then you're mistaken again.  That word, πρωτεύω, refers to the action of having preeminence.  Paul uses a number of words here that all relate to high status.

@MikeSangrey. So if the church is the immediate context, then Paul is not talking about the beginning of creation in Genesis, correct?

@AlexBalilo  The word 'beginning' in verse 18 does not refer to the beginning of creation.

@NepheshRoi, I appreciate that for one who holds to the Diety of Christ you are intellectually honest enough to affirm the literal meaning of firstborn. This is an interesting way at looking "all creation." I don't think I agree with your conclusion as "all things created, those in the heavens, and those upon the earth, those visible, and those invisible, whether thrones, whether lordships, whether principalities, whether authorities;" seems to include the non human thrones and principalities in the heavenly place which are not considered in your other all creation verses.

@Austin – Thanks for your appreciation and kind words, though I smell a trap set for me. I am sorry if you are innocent or unaware of that trap. Let me be careful not to fall into that trap. Now to clarify the issue you raised: definitely “all creation/every creature/pas ktisis” is different from “all things/pas”. The former is related to human beings only and the latter, according to you, is related to including non-human angelic world and if so, goes even before the Genesis creation of the physical universe.

I reiterate my point: Col 1:15 is not connected to Genesis creation but to the resurrection from the dead. Col 1:15-16 follows the same pattern we find in Col 1:18.

Col 1:18:---> Jesus Christ is the First-born out of the dead (human beings). The Man Jesus is given the first place in resurrection. Why is it so? So that He will be preeminent in “all things”. Col 1:15-16:---> Jesus is the First-born of all creation (all human beings). The Man Jesus is given the first place in resurrection. Why is it so? Because “all things” were created by Him and for Him.

@NepheshRoi, I see you've thought this through. Thanks for clarifying. I am just not sure it's plausible that the creation event referred to in the description of Christ in 1:15 is a completely different creation event than the one at the center of 1:16 that's meant to support and amplify the description Christ in 1:15.

By the way I think its possible that v15 refers to the new creation but then v16 would somehow have to as well. I don't think they can refer to different creations.

@Austin – If you will analyze, “firstborn” in the Scripture, whether it refers to Jesus or the church (of the firstborn) always means “from among brothers/out of the dead” as I have shown in my answer; ref. Rom 8:29, Col 1:18, Rev 1:5, Heb 1:6, Heb 12:23. Secondly, “all creation/every creature/pas ktisis” is related to human beings as is clearly mentioned in Mark 16:15 and Col 1:23. It is not related to Genesis creation. However, “all things” are related to pre and post Genesis creation.

But you are right, verse 15 does refer to the new creation of human beings (saints of God – 2 Cor 5:17). The relation between verse 15 and 16 is no more than that given in verse 18 where it says, the First-born out of dead is preeminent to “all things”. So, the First-born of every creature is the Author of “all things”.

I still think that the way v15 and v16 relate to each other v16 amplifies & explains the scope of the creation in v15, but also your argument that creation only refers to men is undermined if we consider that Mark 16 due to textual concerns is likely not scripture at all & that the proclamation made in Col 1:23 is likely in (en) all creation as some translations reveal and not to all creation. Even in Mark 16 it may be understood as "in" and not "to". Finally even if it is "to" & not "in," Rom 8:19-23 shows, in alignment w/ OT, that the good news doesn't just apply to humans but all creation.

You have every freedom to hold on to your convictions. But I didn’t argue “that creation only refers to men”. What I said was that the Scripture defines “all creation/every creature/pas ktisis” in relation to the entire humanity only. Regarding Mark 16, I don’t reject or accept parts of Scripture based on my requirements! Finally “in” or “to”, the gospel is preached not to inanimate things or animals but only to humanity. This is meant in Rom 8:19-23 also. See “all creation/every creature/pas ktisis” in verse 22.

@NepheshRoi, Regarding Mark 16, I don’t reject or accept parts of Scripture based on my requirements! Just to be clear neither do I. But nor do I base my beliefs on text claimed to be scripture that's missing from the earliest and most reliable manuscripts. Finally “in” or “to”, the gospel is preached not to inanimate things or animals but only to humanity.  Yes, but the gospel is preach in all of creation, that is in locations that are not animate and among life that are not human. Lastly, do you believe the "all creation"  in Ro8:22 is different from the creation in vs 20 & 21?

Austin, again it seems you have won the argument. However, frankly, I would like to learn about “locations that are not animate and among life that are not human” where the Gospel was preached.

The OP asks: Why did Paul call Jesus the firstborn from among the dead in Colossians 1:18, when there was no death yet when God began creating? The simple answer is man brought death into the world after it had been created and God's plan of restoration was a new creation of which Jesus was the firstborn from among the dead.
The OP also is asking about the significance of the repetition of firstborn:
Colossians 1 (YLT)

15 who is the image of the invisible God, first-born of all creation, 16 because in him were the all things created, those in the heavens, and those upon the earth, those visible, and those invisible, whether thrones, whether lordships, whether principalities, whether authorities; all things through him, and for him, have been created, 17 and himself is before all, and the all things in him have consisted. 18 And himself is the head of the body -- the assembly -- who is a beginning, a first-born out of the dead, that he might become in all [things] -- himself -- first, 19 because in him it did please all the fulness to tabernacle, 20 and through him to reconcile the all things to himself -- having made peace through the blood of his cross -- through him, whether the things upon the earth, whether the things in the heavens.

The term first-born naturally calls to mind the parent-child relationship. Clearly that cannot be the meaning Paul intends. If Jesus may be called the first-born of the dead, it is only on the basis of His existence before death. First-born of the dead as described here demands pre-existence.
Paul uses the same verb in both descriptions: ἐστιν. First-born is present tense, meaning now; indicative, meaning a statement of fact; active, meaning the subject, Jesus is the "doer," the one performing the action. The active voice precludes an overly simplistic application of the term first-born. Obviously, from the human perspective one cannot be a first-born by one's own actions. With respect to creation, the active voice demands pre-existence to creation: Jesus made Himself "first-born of all creation."
The present tense means He is still now first-born. Again an overly simplistic application is impossible because both first-borns are present tense. The passage states being first-born of the dead in no way altered being first-born of all creation.

The True Answer:
Colossians 1:15 refers to Jesus' pre-incarnation status.
Colossians 1:18 refers to Jesus' post-resurrection status.

"Firstborn of all creation" means that Jesus was the first being to be created by God in the Genesis creation week, begotten on the 1st Day as the Light of the world as the first of God's works before anything else was created (Gen. 1:3, Prov. 8:22, Rev 3:14). Through him and for him was all else created (1 Cor. 8:6, Col 1:15), including the man Adam and his wife on the final 6th Day as the last of God's works (Gen. 1:26, Prov. 8:30).
"Firstborn from among the dead" means that Jesus was the first being to be resurrected from the dead into immortality (Col. 1:18). As he was the Chief Angel of God before his mortal human incarnation, Jesus became the first mortal man to be resurrected into an immortal body and is therefore called the Last Adam. All other humans that were resurrected still died, but Jesus Christ is alive now and forevermore at God's right hand.
Jesus is the firstborn of those alive, and the firstborn of those dead, so that he is "first in everything" (Col. 1:18).
Jesus is the first being to be created by God, and the first mortal being to be resurrected into immortality by God.
Colossians 1:15-18 is about both the Genesis begetting of Christ (to make him firstborn over all physical creation), and also the resurrection of Christ as the first man to gain immortality after death (to make him firstborn over all the dead). Colossians 1:15-18 is about Christ being preeminent over both the old creation and the new creation.
I hope this cleared things up for you. There is no need for anyone to overcomplicate this.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I downvoted this answer because it reflects an interpretation which is inconsistent with the actual text. Jesus is, ἐστιν. first-born. The verb is present tense, indicative, active, meaning He is the performer of the action. Literally, He made Himself first-born of all creation and first-born of the dead. Moreover, the present tense means He is now the first-born of all creation and first-born of the dead. With respect ot the term first-born He is the same. The passage is quite clear. There is no need to overly complicate with interpretation inconsistent with the Greek text.
